# iOS UIButton with custom shapes

Tags: ios, uibutton, quartz-core

How to create 2 buttons in iOS with custom shapes. I need to draw two buttons like Diagonal of a rectangle. Left side is one button and right side is another button. I've tried using Bezier paths, But how to make them adaptive for all devices ?

Here is my code that I've tried for one button

```
 UIBezierPath*  bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 138, 118)];
[UIColor.blackColor setStroke];
bezierPath.lineWidth = 20;
[bezierPath stroke];


CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.frame = self.Btn.bounds;
shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.CGPath;
shapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
shapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 120;
self.Btn.layer.mask = shapeLayer;
```

Comment: can you show a picture example of what you want?

Comment: Take a look at [OBShapedButton](https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton). With this, you can overlap 2 `UIButton`s giving them an appearance of a single button, and either button will respond only if you tap an area over the image only. However, you will need custom images for your button.

Answer (score 1):

cant u just do one button,

subclass it and hittest the CGPoint to determine which shape you should set highlighted/selected/etc